# SybaseIQ issue on Disconnecting named pipe (on a LOAD TABLE)

Tags: c++, sap-iq

I have an issue trying to perform bulk load using named pipe on  SybaseIQ 15.4.
The code is C++ and turns on Windows.

At the end of the bulk, after flushing the buffer (*`FlushFileBuffers`*), when I try to disconnect the named pipe (*`DisconnectNamedPipe`*), the running *`LOAD TABLE query`* crash with an *`"I/O Error on file \\.\pipe\pipename"`* although the doc says:

`"The pipe writer must call FlushFileBuffers( ) and then DisconnectNamedPipe( ). (If you do not, Sybase IQ reports an exception from hos io::Read( ).) This issues a PIPE_NOT_CONNECTED error, which notifies Sybase IQ that the pipe was shut down in an orderly manner rather than an uncontrolled disconnect"`

Note that if I remove the `DisconnectNamedPipe`, the bulk load is fine

Here is a resume of the code, Thank for your help

```
hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(strPipeName, PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND, PIPE_TYPE_BYTE, 255, 65536, 65536, 100, NULL);

ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL);

// in another thread: LOAD TABLE myTable (...) USING CLIENT FILE strPipeName ...

WriteFile(hPipe, ...);

FlushFileBuffers(hPipe);
DisconnectNamedPipe(hPipe); // I/O Error on file \\.\pipe\pipename
CloseHandle(hPipe);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a Sybase IQ bug. 
Using 15.2 or using the last EBR for the 15.4, the DisconnectNamedPipe works fine